# Unable to get request token and request access secret in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.6, magento

In magento from admin panel I can have the customer key and customer secret key.. I have install oauth on my system But for getting the access token i give the url as : *http://192.168.1.101:8010/magento/oauth/token* but it returns as:

```
      This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://192.168.1.101:8010/magento/oauth/token
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.
```

How can i get resolve of this...

Comment: afaik has OAuth to communicate with the server. Twitter can't access your local system, so this error raises.

Comment: Then how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: make your server public accessable. dyndns.org might help, or if you have a static IP you can use it. Configure youre firewall and router to forward the packages on port 8010 to your pc. But this is far away of my expertise :)